# JavaScript: Sort an array of String numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of school grades that looks like the following.

(Note 'N' stands for no grades and 'K' stands for kindergarten)

> const toSort = ['1','3','4','5','6','7','9','10','11','12','K','2','N','8'];

Using the JavaScript sort() method, I would like to arrange the array so it will look like:

> const sorted = ['K','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','N'];

Here is my attempt at it:

```js
const toSort = ['1', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '10', '11', '12', 'K', '2', 'N', '8'];

toSort.sort();
// Produces: ["1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "K", "N"]

const test = toSort.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === 'K') {
    return -1;
  }

  return Number(a) < Number(b) ? -1 : Number(a) > Number(b) ? 1 : 0;
});

console.log(test)
```

https://jsbin.com/pocajayala/1/edit?html,js,console,output

How I can resolve this?

Comment: Why K at the start and N at the end ?

Comment: What's the sorting logic that needs to be implemented? Why is `K` < 1 while `N` > 12?

Comment: These are school grades. 'N' stands for no grade, 'K' stands for kindergarten

Comment: Just like `'K'`, make a special case for `'N'`. Then convert everything else to a `Number`. No need for any ternary operators.

Comment: Your issue is that `Number("K")` and `Number("N")` are both `NaN`. You only remove the case where the parameter `a` is `"K"`, not where `b` is `"K"` or where either is `"N"`.

Comment: Alternatively, just hardcode the array in the order you wish and then use it for whatever else you are doing.

Comment: Tthe trivial fix for your code is adding `if (b === "K") return 1; if (a === "N") return 1; if (b === "N") return -1;`. This still has an issue, because if e.g. one "N" is compared to another "N" (which doesn't happen in the test case), theoretically your sort function is not proper. In any implementation i know of, this doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
const toSort = ['1', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '10', '11', '12', 'K', '2', 'N', '8'];

const test = toSort.sort((a, b) => {
 // console.log('a ' + a + ' b ' + b);
 if (a === "K" || b === "N") {
  return -1;
 }
 if (a === "N" || b === "K") {
  return 1;
 }
 return +a - +b;
});

console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use the string's native prototype [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function like so:

```
['1', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '10', '11', '12', 'K', '2', 'N', '8']
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }))

//  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "K", "N"]
```

It works well with numbers among other characters too.

Comment: Learned a new native function, thanks! that's a clean solution

Comment: What a smart solution. I really like this.

Answer (score 6):

I would do it like this:

```js
const toSort = ['1', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '9', '10', '11', '12', 'K', '2', 'N', '8'];

const transform = k => {
    if (k === 'K') return 0;
    else if (k === 'N') return 13;
    else return +k;
}

const test = toSort.sort((a, b) => transform(a) - transform(b));

console.log(test);
```

In case your letters don't have correlation with those specific numbers, and instead are always the biggest and the smallest, you can use `Infinity` and `-Infinity` on the `transform` function.

```
const transform = k => {
    if (k === 'K') return -Infinity;
    else if (k === 'N') return Infinity;
    else return +k;
}
```

Comment: `return k == 'K' ? 0 : k == 'N' ? 13 : +k` if you felt like minifying it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this helps you

```js
const toSort = ['1','3','4','5','6','7','9','10','11','12','K','2','N','8'];

toSort.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a == 'K') {
    return -1; // always K is smaller
  }
  if(a == 'N')  {
    return 1 // always N is bigger
  }
  if(b == 'K') {
    return 1;
  }
  if(b == 'N')  {
    return -1
  }
  return Number(a) - Number(b);
});

console.log(toSort);
```