# How can I sort a string of numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, sorting

Given the following function:

```
function sortFunction(str) {
  // return srt
}
console.log(sortFunction("20 150 2343 20 9999"));
```

I am trying to make a function that returns an string with the same sequence of numbers, but sorted by **the sum of its characters**.

So I should get ("20 150 2343 9999"). What happens with "20"? If 2 numbers are of the same value, I need to sort them as strings.

Comment: please add your code. what does not work?

Comment: Hello, consider adding your code to get some help. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be this:

```js
const sortFunction = str =>
  /* Keep only numbers groups */ str.match(/\d+/g)
  /* Ascending sort           */    .sort((a, b) => +a-b)
  /* Remove duplicates        */    .filter((c, i, t) => !i || t[i-1] != c) // 1st OR != prev
  /* Rebuild a string         */    .join(' ');

console.log(sortFunction("20 150 2343 20 9999")); // 20 150 2343 9999
```

Comment: I like this answer because it's the most precise, but am on the fence due to its complexity and inefficiency.

Comment: @expressjs123  I made it more simpler ;)

Comment: It's a lot better now