# Grouping rows by day and month. Error by month between days 9 and 10 on every month

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I got this script which will read column 1 where I have the dates, and will group all rows by month and within these will group rows by day. This is because within each day I've got a row for every hour or 4 hours or so.

When the script is executed it will first group by day,then by month.
When the month grouping part is executed, when there is within a certain month days 9 and 10, it will group the 2 last rows of the 9th and the 2 first rows of the 10th and will not group by month.

If the column does not contain days 9 and 10. Let's say if I only have data between 16 and 31 this error does not happen.

Can't figure out where the problem is on this script. How can I prevent this error with the month grouping when there is the 9th and 10th of a month?

```
function groupRow() {

    const timeZone = "GMT+1";
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const rowStart = 5;
    const rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
    const values = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
    const o = [];

    values.forEach((date, i) => {
        const [m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, "yyyyMM,dd").split(",");
        if (!o[m]) {
            o[m] = [];
        }
        if (!o[m][d]) {
            o[m][d] = [];
        }
        o[m][d].push(rowStart + i);
    });

    var collator = new Intl.Collator([], {numeric: true});

    for (var m in o) {
     o[m] = Object.values(o[m]).sort((a,b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
    }

    Object.values(o).forEach(m => {
        for (const d of m) {
            if (d.length === 1) {
            continue;
            }
            const range = `${ d[1] }:${ d.slice(-1)[0] }`;
            sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
        }
        const a = m.flat();
        if (a.length === 1) {
            return;
        }
        const range = `${ a[1] }:${ a.slice(-1)[0] }`;
        sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    });
}
```

[image]

Here's the link for dummy file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT:
Actually if I delete all the rows for the 9th the error still happens with the 8th and 10th. If I delete all the rows for the 10th the error does not happen. It seems to be connected to the first row for the 10th day.

EDIT2:
Updated code with answer given by Yuri Khristich below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to sort your `o` object/array this way:

```
var collator = new Intl.Collator([], {numeric: true});
    
for (var m in o) {
 o[m] = Object.values(o[m]).sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a, b));
}
```

instead of:

```
for (const m in o) {
  o[m] = Object.values(o[m]);
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57255344/14265469

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you.

Comment: Actually it's even simper. It doesn't even need the fancy`collator`. You can sort it in a more common way: `o[m] = Object.values(o[m]).sort((a,b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));`

Comment: Btw I am trying to make this script also group by year. Do you have any idea how I could go about doing that? Tried adding [y] also yyy,MM,dd etc but doesn't seem to work. Maybe I should ask another question for this?

Comment: Honestly, your algorithm is quite complex. I barely could to guess out the sorting thing. So I can't answer right away how it can be expanded to group by years. I think this problem worth a new question. Here are much more experienced coders than me. And probably it makes sense to add the tag `JavaScript`, since this particular part of the code is pure JS, not even GAS. And the tag JavaScript is a quite hot tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your spreadsheet settings (**File>Settings**) have time zone set to GMT+00:00 and you use GMT+1 in `Utilities.formatDate`

Comment: I know but for some reason if I change the timezone in the settings to match the timezone in the script, or vice versa, the first row of a day gets grouped with the day before. But this is another issue. If I change the timezones to match this problem with the 9th and 10th still persists.