# How To sort a numeric String array using JavaScript

Tags: arrays, sorting

**["12 ab","5 Python langauge", "7 JavaScript"]**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sort strings in javascript numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107226/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript-numerically)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.