# Arrange the following array in ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I came across this array question in my Javascript interview and I couldn't think the logic of it. There is an array of strings given and we have to arrange it in ascending order.

const arr = ['sd101', 'zt099', 'tr134', 'gh234', 'cv056'];

Now we have to create a function that will take the arr as an argument and return the array in ascending order.
so the output should be ['cv056', 'zt099', 'sd101', 'tr134', 'gh234']

Here we can see the sorting is happening in the ascending order of numbers. So we are not taking alphabetical characters into account.

Comment: or [How to sort strings in JavaScript numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107226/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript-numerically)

Comment: No, this is not helpful. I can see why the confusion so I have edited the question.

Comment: Please add the code you have written and point out what's not working with your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the links you received in comments, if you know for sure that there will be only 3 numbers at the end and they are zero-filled, then you can do this:

```js
const arr = ['sd101', 'zt099', 'tr134', 'gh234', 'cv056'];
arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.slice(-3)) - parseInt(b.slice(-3)));
console.log(arr);       // prints out: ['cv056', 'zt099', 'sd101', 'tr134', 'gh234']
```

I've tried it out and it seems that in JavaScript you don't even need to parse the int, so:

```js
arr.sort((a, b) => a.slice(-3) - b.slice(-3));
```

also works, but I'm not sure if there are any edge cases which it would not.