# Sort file names in photoshop script (javascript)

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to sort the files present within a folder by their names.
The following funtion is working very nicely, but sometimes it's not able to sort the files if the file names prepend with 0.

[image]

You can note that it could place 04 before 4,  05 before 5 and 06 before 6. But it could sort the other files.

This is the function code -

```
function sortAlphaNum(a, b) {
try {
    var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
    var reN = /[^0-9]/g;
    var AInt = parseInt(a, 10);
    var BInt = parseInt(b, 10);

    if (isNaN(AInt) && isNaN(BInt)) {
        var aA = a.replace(reA, "");
        var bA = b.replace(reA, "");
        if (aA === bA) {
            var aN = parseInt(a.replace(reN, ""), 10);
            var bN = parseInt(b.replace(reN, ""), 10);
            return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
        }
    } else if (isNaN(AInt)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (isNaN(BInt)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return AInt > BInt ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
catch(e) {
    alert(e + ': Line ' + e.line);
}
```

}

Can you please suggest me how to sort the files as they are shown in the windows explorer?

Thanks
Nirmalya

Comment: You're looking for natural sorting. have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings-in-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107226/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript-numerically)