# Sort array key and values pair with key ending with digits using Javascript/D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, sharepoint

I thought I had this figured out but I was wrong.  I'm experiencing a strange issue with sorting the key string ending with a number/digit.  When I sort my data to display from highest (newest item added) to the lowest (oldest item added); it seems to sort the key string with the single numbers on top as a group, then the multiple digit numbers will underneath the single numbers.  When a new location is added (new one or adding another existing location the array returns random sequence results; not adhering to the sort order, from newest to the oldest. I tried many sort methods, it will sorts but I get the same results mentioned.  Below is the code I'm using to show the different location and its number of time it's listed.

My data array from the console.  I am fetching the data from a SharePoint list.

```
Array(16) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​
0: Object { key: "Location-9", values: 1 }
​
1: Object { key: "Location-8", values: 5 }
​
2: Object { key: "Location-7", values: 5 }
​
3: Object { key: "Location-6", values: 5 }
​
4: Object { key: "Location-5", values: 14 }
​
5: Object { key: "Location-4", values: 10 }
​
6: Object { key: "Location-3", values: 8 }
​
7: Object { key: "Location-2", values: 6 }
​
8: Object { key: "Location-16", values: 5 }
​
9: Object { key: "Location-15", values: 2 }
​
10: Object { key: "Location-14", values: 2 }
​
11: Object { key: "Location-13", values: 2 }
​
12: Object { key: "Location-12", values: 2 }
​
13: Object { key: "Location-11", values: 2 }
​
14: Object { key: "Location-10", values: 2 }
​
15: Object { key: "Location-1", values: 15 }
```

My script for counting the number of times the Location was added to the SharePoint list:

```
data = chartData;

data.sort(function (a, b) { return b.key < a.key ? -1 : 1;})

var LocationCount  = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.value; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
  .entries(data);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort strings in JavaScript numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107226/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript-numerically)

Comment: If the leading string is always the same than just read the number `+b.key.match(/\d+/)[0]`

Comment: I tried similar methods but how do I target the "key: Location-..." to fall in sequence and stay when there is an update, i.e., Location-16, Location-15, Location-14, down to Location-1?   When I apply these different sort method there is no change in the order, it say the same.

Comment: Epascarello - When I updated my sort with your suggestion I get the following error.  Uncaught TypeError: b.key is undefined. My update: data.sort(function (a, b) { return +b.key.match(/\d+/)[0] < a.key ? -1 : 1;}).  Is this was what you were suggestion to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{
    key: "Location-9",
    values: 1
  },
  {
    key: "Location-8",
    values: 5
  },
  {
    key: "Location-7",
    values: 5
  },
  {
    key: "Location-6",
    values: 5
  },
  {
    key: "Location-5",
    values: 14
  },
  {
    key: "Location-4",
    values: 10
  },
  {
    key: "Location-3",
    values: 8
  },
  {
    key: "Location-2",
    values: 6
  },
  {
    key: "Location-16",
    values: 5
  },
  {
    key: "Location-15",
    values: 2
  },
  {
    key: "Location-14",
    values: 2
  },
  {
    key: "Location-13",
    values: 2
  },
  {
    key: "Location-12",
    values: 2
  },
  {
    key: "Location-11",
    values: 2
  },
  {
    key: "Location-10",
    values: 2
  },
  {
    key: "Location-1",
    values: 15
  }
];

//id for reference for sorting purpose
arr.forEach((element) => {
  element.id = element.key.split("-")[1];
});
//sort the value from ascending;
let ascSort = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.id - b.id;
});
//sort the value from descending;
let descSort = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.id - a.id;
});

//deleted id not required
arr.forEach((element) => {
  delete element.id;
});



//console.log(ascSort);
console.log(descSort)
```

Comment: Thank you Mahadev.  It worked! This seems like the best solution for what I was seeking to achieve.  It handles new updates and the script don't shift when a new item is added to list, it stay in sequence.  I really appreciate the help with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the numeric value of the key and sort by it. The extraction during sorting seems to work faster:

```html
<script name="benchmark" data-count="1000000">
const arr=[{key:"Location-9",values:1},{key:"Location-8",values:5},{key:"Location-7",values:5},{key:"Location-6",values:5},{key:"Location-5",values:14},{key:"Location-4",values:10},{key:"Location-3",values:8},{key:"Location-2",values:6},{key:"Location-16",values:5},{key:"Location-15",values:2},{key:"Location-14",values:2},{key:"Location-13",values:2},{key:"Location-12",values:2},{key:"Location-11",values:2},{key:"Location-10",values:2},{key:"Location-1",values:15}];

// @benchmark extract keys during sorting
arr.sort((a, b) => (a.id ??= a.key.match(/\d+$/)[0]) - (b.id ??= b.key.match(/\d+$/)[0]))

// @benchmark extract keys separately
arr.forEach(item => item.id = item.key.match(/\d+$/)[0])
arr.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
</script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/silentmantra/benchmark/master/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alexander, I appreciate your solution.  It also worked for me.  The only issue is the Benchmark.min.js.  I have to get it approved by my IT department to use and I don't have the time to wait for their approval :)  But I will keep this solution on file for future use.

Comment: @TonyT you can copy my code from `<script>` and console.log the result manually. also the code in the snippet is executed in a iframe's sandbox and cannot harm your device in any way, the stackoverflow.com cares about that

Comment: @TonyT if you find my answer helpful you could upvote (the arrow up) or/and accept (the checkbox) my answer that way i'll be motivated to answer you in the future.

Comment: Hello Alexander will do.  I should have known that :)  The script can be that way. Thank you for the assist - your solution works perfect as well and solves the problem I was encountering.

Comment: @TonyT and it's strange you've accepted an answer with a slower and less elegant solution

Comment: Hello Alexander.  I selected the solution above because I tested his first and it worked for me, in my test environment.  After seeing the solution worked, I place it in my real world environment.  Then I tested your solution in my test environment and seen it worked also.  But until we discussed my concern of the attached JS library you used, getting it approved by my IT, which your answer satisfied.  I left the top solution in place in my real world environment.  I thought it was only fair to accept the top solution.  But both works great.  Maybe this site can credit both as accepted.